# How can I change material ui datepicker language and default timezone?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I change the language of a Material-UI date picker? It doesn't seem to fully work for the whole date picker.

What my current date picker looks like:

[image: Current datepicker]

Comment: [Importing MomentUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58677350/how-to-change-the-language-for-keyboarddatepicker-material-ui/58677438#58677438) might do the trick. Change locale to your language (example is spanish)

Comment: Yo need to import your locale language onyl like `` import 'moment/locale/es'`` for example

Answer (score 11):

If you are using day.js adapter

```
import "dayjs/locale/es";
import "dayjs/locale/en";

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="es">
or
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="en">
```

with i18

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale= 
{i18n?.language}>
```

with moment.js

```
import 'moment/locale/es'
import 'moment/locale/en'
```

Answer (score 10):

@MUI5 solution

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import {es} from 'date-fns/locale'
import {TextField} from "@mui/material";

export const MyDatePicker = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date())
  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue)
  }

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider locale={es} dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Date desktop"
        inputFormat="dd-MMMM-yyyyy"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! importing the locale `from 'date-fns/locale'` into `LocalizationProvider` was a great call!

Comment: `locale={es}` has being deprecated, use `adapterLocale={es}` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to use `date-fns` in addition to the @Shikyo solution: :

```js
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import { fr } from "date-fns/locale";

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider locale={fr} utils={DateFnsUtils}>
...
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: This still works with the new [MUI 5 / MUI X DatePicker components](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/) too.

Comment: I think this is the solution. In my case `utils={DateFnsUtils}` was not needed.

Answer (score 3):

It's on the bottom of the documentation page https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker

```
<DatePicker
    okLabel="Text"
    clearLabel="Text"
    cancelLabel="Text"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: As I understand, he requested to change the local, currently, it's Russian.

Comment: What if I want to specify clearLabel 1 time (global) for all DatePickers?

Comment: @Zakhar Correct me if I am wrong but I don't think you can. I have wrapped the DataPicker in my own component  where the label properties get set and that is what I use instead of the DataPicker itself.

Comment: @Shikyo Agreed, I did the same

Comment: That solution only fixes the buttons, not days of week and months.

Answer (score 0):

The following page of the docs looks like it should be what you want: https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/localization/date-fns

This page has an example of changing the locale with a menu item. Specifically, if you want to just provide one locale you can pass the prop `locale` into the component `MuiPickersUtilsProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the locales depending on the adapter, here is a possible solution with dayjs in the Material UI documentation:

https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/localization/

Answer (score 0):

'locale' is deprecated. use this instead:

```
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { deDE } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/locales';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';

<LocalizationProvider
  localeText={deDE.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}
>
  <DatePicker />
</LocalizationProvider>;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone use dayjs it's struggling with it you can:

```
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date- 
pickers/AdapterDayjs'
import 'dayjs/locale/it';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

dayjs.locale('it'); // THIS ! 

<LocalizationProvider
   dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
   {children}
</LocalizationProvider>
```

This is the only working solution I found